# How to ignore a lambda when comparing for equality?

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito

Given this class:

```kotlin
data class MyClass(
    val foo: String,
    val bar: () -> Unit
)
```

I want to assert that two instances of MyClass are equal, ignoring the lambda field `bar`. How do I make this work with Mockito?

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```kotlin
        val actual = MyClass("foo", bar = {})
        val expected = MyClass("foo", bar = Mockito.any())

        assertEquals(expected, actual)
```

Comment: You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods for the data class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without changing the Class:**

1. You could create the `expected` by copying the `actual` field. For example:

   ```
   val expected = actual.copy(foo = "foo")
   ```
2. If the `object` is instantiated elsewhere, then you could create a copy of the `actual` field. For example:

   ```
   assertEquals(expected, actual.copy(bar = expected.bar)
   ```

**Changing the Class:**

1. Only fields inside the primary constructor are taken into account when building the `equals` method. You could remove the `bar` field from the primary constructor. For example:

   ```
   data class MyClass(
       val foo: String
   ) {
       val bar: () -> Unit = {}
   }
   ```
2. You could override the `equals` method in the class. For example:

   ```
   data class MyClass(
       val foo: String,
       val bar: () -> Unit
   ) {
       override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
           return (other as? MyClass)?.foo == foo
       }

       override fun hashCode(): Int {
           return foo.hashCode()
       }
   }
   ```